# Parallel execution of bash task from python, extracting csv columns

Tags: python, bash

I have a csv file with 7,221,032 columns and 37 rows. I need to map each column to a separate file, ideally from a python script. My attempt so far:

```
num_features = 7221032
binary_dir = "data_binary"

command_template = command = 'awk -F "\\"*,\\"*" \'{print $%s}\' %s/images_binary.txt > %s/feature_files/pixel_%s.vector'

batch_size = 100

batch_indexes = np.arange(1, num_features, batch_size)

for batch_index in batch_indexes[1:5]:

    indexes = range(batch_index-batch_size, batch_index)

    commands = [command_template % (str(i), binary_dir, binary_dir, str(i)) for i in indexes]
    map(os.system, commands)
```

But, this appears to be rather a slow process.. Any advice on how to speed it up?

Comment: Numpy can read csv. Do you need awk?

Comment: The file is ~500mb though... And I'd then like to work with significantly larger files. Would rather not load everything in ram

Comment: You could look at using Dask or pyspark

Answer (score 0):

Revised solution - using Perl

Run with perl prog.pl < /path/to/images_binary.txt

Runtime is 10 sec for 100,000 items. Will take about 7 hours for complete data set. Not sure that running parallel will do better, since the bottleneck is open/close of files. You best choice to improve perform will be to reduce the number of generated files, somehow get the input written in column order first.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

while ( my $x = <> ) {
    chomp $x ;
    my @v = split(',', $x) ;
    foreach my $i (0..$#v) {
        open OF, ">data_binary/feature_files/pixel_$i.vector" ;
        print OF $v[$i], "\n" ;
        close OF ;
    } ;
} ;
```

Comment: It's 7 million fields, not 37.  So 7 million new files. I'm sure that awk won't like that many open files, so you'd have to append to the file and close it after each print.

Comment: Oops, I misread the question. You are correct - not a job for awk. Are you sure you want 7M files ? it's going to be hard to process that many files in a single folder ?